# Does the lattice of ideals of a ring know which ideals are prime?

Tags: commutative-algebra, order-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> If two rings have isomorphic lattices of ideals and one them is a domain, is the other necessarily a domain?

The rings in question are commutative and have an element $1$.

**EDIT.** I apologize for a lot of useless edits. I convinced myself that it was natural to require that our lattice isomorphism preserve arbitrary joins and meets, and that I had missed this subtlety; and I edited the question accordingly. Then Eric Wofsey observed that lattice isomorphisms automatically preserve arbitrary joins and meets. So I made at least two mistakes: (1) I failed to think of the completeness condition, (2) I thought that it was necessary to require it!

Comment: @Arthur - If the answer to the body question is Yes, then you can answer the title question by saying: given an ideal $I$, look at the sublattice formed by the ideals containing $I$. If this sublattice is the lattice of ideals of a domain, the answer the title question is Yes, and otherwise it is No.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It is basically the same question.

Comment: Does the isomorphism, say $\varphi$, satisfiy $\varphi(IJ)=\varphi(I)\varphi(J)$?

Comment: @RenanManeliMezabarba - No, at least not a priori. A priori it's just a lattice isomorphism. I agree that, if it preserves product of ideals, it preserves prime ideals.

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard A couple of notes: (1) Perhaps you should specify that the isomorphism is a complete isomorphism of lattices, i.e. respects arbitrary joins and meets.  Things might get weird and the equivalence of your questions might get lost otherwise.  (2) We can reduce this to a question about radical ideals quite easily.  Being a domain is the same thing as being irreducible (finite intersections of non-zero ideals are non-zero) and reduced (no non-zero nilpotents).......

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard (cont.) Lattice isomorphisms obviously detect the property of being irreducible, so if a reduced ring is lattice-isomorphic to a domain, then it is a domain.

Comment: @BadamBaplan - I don't know how to thank you! I edited the question. It would be great if you answered it! (I'm studying your comments.)

Comment: An isomorphism of lattices automatically preserves arbitrary joins and meets.

Comment: My bad for a useless first comment about complete homorphisms.  In the second point I was just trying to say that the lattice knows about its prime ideals iff it knows about its radical ideals.  This is a pretty trivial observation, but helpful in seeing that for some special classes of rings, like Jacobson rings, a lattice of ideals does know about its primes.  In general I guess lattices of ideals are in the dark about their radicals, and like Eric Wofsey was doing, I bet you can produce a simple example from chain rings, one with nilpotents and one without.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  For instance, let $A$ be a valuation ring with value group $\mathbb{Q}$, and let $B=A/I$ where $I$ is the ideal of elements of valuation at least $1$.  Ideals in $A$ canonically correspond to upward-closed subsets of $[0,\infty)\cap\mathbb{Q}$ with the inclusion order.  Similarly, ideals in $B$ correspond to upward-closed subsets of $[0,1)\cap\mathbb{Q}$.  Since $[0,\infty)\cap\mathbb{Q}$ and $[0,1)\cap\mathbb{Q}$ are order-isomorphic, so are the lattices of ideals in $A$ and $B$ (explicitly, they are each order-isomorphic to the Cantor set with a greatest element added on). However, $A$ is a domain and $B$ is not.

Comment: @reuns: That's not quite right; there are also ideals $\{a\in A:v(a)\geq t\}$ if $t$ is rational.

Comment: Sure I was repairing that. $A=  \bigcup_n k[x]_{(x)}[x^{1/n}]$ with $v(x^{m/n} f) = m/n, f\in \bigcup_n (k^*+x^{1/n} A)$, for any $t\in \Bbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ and interval $U = [t,\infty]$ or $U = (t,\infty]$ then $I_U = \{ a\in A, v(a)\in U\}$ is an ideal and there are no others.

The ideals of $A/I_{[1,\infty]}$ correspond to the $t \le 1$ and sending $t\in [0,1]$ to $t/(1-t)\in [0,\infty]$ is an isomorphism of the lattices.

Comment: @EricWofsey - Thank you very much for this great answer, the clarifying comment and the edit! What a mess this question would have been without you!